# Loading Image Into File Using Picasso On Activity Result.

Tags: android, picasso

I have an activity that tries to call the below method in its onActivtyResult method

```
private void loadTempFile(Uri originalImgUri) {
    final Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            try {
                String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                String absolutePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                    absolutePath = PhotoUtils.getFilesPath(getApplicationContext());
                }

                // If the output directory for the file isn't there, we make it
                File outputDirectory = new File(absolutePath);
                if (!outputDirectory.exists()) {
                    outputDirectory.mkdirs();
                }

                tempPhotoUri = absolutePath + "/temp.jpg";
                tempPhoto = new File(tempPhotoUri);
                tempPhoto.createNewFile();
                Timber.d(String.format("Upload temp file created: %s", tempPhoto.exists()));

                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(tempPhoto);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Timber.d(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        }
    };

    Picasso.with(PhotoUploadActivity.this)
            .load(originalImgUri)
            .resize(RESIZE_IMAGE_DIMENSION, RESIZE_IMAGE_DIMENSION)
            .noPlaceholder()
            .onlyScaleDown()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(target);
}
```

onBitmapLoaded is never called. any advice?

I've tried moving target into the class and basically everywhere else....

Comment: Maybe you're getting an error, but `onBitmapFailed()` has an empty implementation. You will never know if you don't log it at least.

Comment: @FlávioFaria I had a log and breakpoint there but removed it since it wasn't the problem / for brevity

Comment: Your code seems fine. Have you checked logcat? How is your connectivity? Have you tried other URLs?

Comment: nothing helpful in logcat, just the crash caused by the method not being called